Moving local git repo from Mac OS to external hard drive (APFS case-insensitive) - will there be problems?
I have a local git repo on my M1 Mac Mini (running Sonoma 14.6.1) that I would like to move to an external hard drive (to free up space on my Mac). The external hard drive drive is new (empty) and has been formatted to APFS (case-insensitive), because I read that this is the best compatibility with Macs (Mac OS being case-insensitive itself).
I would like to move my local git repo (fullpath is /Users/a/b/c/d) to the external harddrive (fullpath is /Volumes/hDrive).
My best guess so far is to do the following
mv /Users/a/b/c/d/* mv /Users/a/b/c/d/.* /Volumes/hDrive/

which would move all files, directories, hidden files, and hidden directories (including .git) to my hard drive. (this suggestion found on https://www.baeldung.com/linux/move-files-hidden-parent)
However, I have read that generally, git is case-sensitive (because Linux is), and that this might induce problems when moving to a case-insensitive hard drive. However, this directory has only ever been used on my Mac which is case-insensitive and I've never had issues.
1 Will the command line code I provided above do what I'd like it to do?
2 Will I run into any problems moving the local git repo from my Mac to a case-insensitive hard drive?

Instead of mv, use cp -R to copy the files to the new drive. That way, you'll always have a copy that you can remove once you ascertained that the repo is working on the new drive. FWIW, this is off-topic for StackOverflow.
